# Integration of StreetView with QGIS2web openlayers map failed

Tags: javascript, openlayers, jquery, google-street-view

After attaching the street view to my map I have most of options gone.
Predominantly I see the error:

**TypeError: S.hasRenderer is not a function**

[image]

My full code is here:

https://mktest.opx.pl/

If I switch off the Street View section completely, then everything starts working.

What is the reason for this behavior?

UPDATE:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
 <script src="./resources/ol.js"></script>
```

There are 2 `ol.js` files linked, which might cause a conflict. However:
removing first off them results an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'proj')
at ol-street-view.js:4
at ol-street-view.js:5**

Link to file:

https://github.com/GastonZalba/ol-street-view/blob/master/dist/ol-street-view.js

when the second link is removed then the following error appears:

**Uncaught TypeError: interact__default.default is not a function
at addPegmanInteraction (ol-street-view.js:425)
at addPegmanControl (ol-street-view.js:508)
at StreetView._createMapControls (ol-street-view.js:548)
at new StreetView (ol-street-view.js:176)
at qgis2web.js:1310**

Comment: OpenLayers 2 and OpenLayers 6 are not compatible.  Have you tried using this example code https://github.com/GastonZalba/ol-street-view/tree/master/examples ?  You should also be aware of clause 3.2.3 (e) in these terms https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms

Comment: Despite attaching ol-street-view.js the console still says, that StreetView is not definied.

Comment: It works for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pbEP.png when I replace the `../dist/` links with `unpkg.com` as in https://github.com/GastonZalba/ol-street-view#readme  You will need a Google maps API key for a full color image.

Comment: I know, that this option works, as mine was working either when I ran this example. The problem occurs on my own map in the link I've attached. Despite all links provided the console cannot detect var Streetview = Streetview... here is the problem.

Comment: Any orher errors in the browser debugger console or network section?

Comment: Nothing really. Or at least I don't know how to check it.

Comment: This is still the same code:  https://mktest.opx.pl/

Comment: You are loading `ol.js` twice. First time it's from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js. Then you load `ol-street-view.js` and then again `ol.js` from https://mktest.opx.pl/resources/ol.js. The second load probably overrides `ol.js` link with `ol-street-view.js`.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed it and sorted it already. Thank you for your help.